# number of ways $3$ teachers can be invited for a guest lecturer on $6$ days in a school

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways $3$ teachers can be invited for a guest lecturer on $6$ days in a school so that every teacher is invited at least once (on any given day exactly one teacher is invited)

Try: First Teacher $T_{1}$ has $6$ possiability (In any one of $6$ days)

Second Teacher $T_{2}$ has $5$ Possiability

Third Teacher $T_{3}$ has $4$ possiability

So total $6\times 5 \times 4 = 120$

But answer given as $540$

Could some help me how to count total ways so the answer is $540$

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are only filling 3 days.  You need a guest on all 6 days.  So, some teachers will need to repeat.  There does not appear to be a further restriction so it could be that all visit twice or one comes four times and the others just once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undesired events:

- A single teacher teaches repeately. $3$ ways to do so.
- Only two teachers. First choose one of the teacher to exclude him/her, and then we avoid two extreme cases where one teacher teaches everyday.

$$3\cdot (2^6-2)$$

Hence the undesired outcomes are $$3(2^6-1)$$

Without restriction, we could have $3^6$. Hence

$$3^6-3(2^6-1)=3(3^5-2^6+1)=3(243-64+1)=3(180)=540$$

Answer (score 1):

The table shows the teacher, the number of visits and the number of ways:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
T_1&T_2&T_3&\text{No of visits}\\
\hline
1&1&4&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 1}=\color{red}{30}\\
1&2&3&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 2}=\color{green}{60}\\
1&3&2&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 3}=\color{green}{60}\\
1&4&1&{6\choose 1}{5\choose 4}=\color{red}{30}\\
2&1&3&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 1}=\color{green}{60}\\
2&2&2&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}=\color{blue}{90}\\
2&3&1&{6\choose 2}{4\choose 3}=\color{green}{60}\\
3&1&2&{6\choose 3}{3\choose 1}=\color{green}{60}\\
3&2&1&{6\choose 3}{3\choose 2}=\color{green}{60}\\
4&1&1&{6\choose 4}{2\choose 1}=\color{red}{30}\\
\hline
&&&\color{red}{90}+\color{green}{360}+\color{blue}{90}=540.
\end{array}$$